# Phalcon 2.1.0 executeQuery() - subquery

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, phalcon

```
$phql = "SELECT t1.* FROM (SELECT u.* FROM \App\Models\User as u) as t1";
$modelsManager = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager();
$modelsManager->setDI($this->getDi());
$query = $modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
```

> Syntax error, unexpected token (, near to 'SELECT u.* FROM
>   \App\Models\User as u) as t1', when parsing: SELECT t1.* FROM
>   (SELECT u.* FROM \App\Models\User as u) as t1 (62)

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure your table name is `\App\Models\User`?

Comment: Remove the first \ before `\App\Models\User`. So it becomes `App\Models\User`. I came across this issue once, and this solved it for me

Comment: Also, the correct syntax for giving an alias to a table is `SELECT * FROM table_name alias_name` not `SELECT * FROM table_name as alias_name` ( so without the "as" )